# What is the more efficient way to compute the max of a list?

Tags: python

I've been messing with Python a little bit and realized that I've been computing the max of a list the wrong way all this time !

This piece of code (which I've been using up to now :/)

```
mylist = [randint(0,1000) for _ in range(10**6)]
mymax = mylist[0]
for elm in mylist:
    mymax = max(elm, mymax)
```

takes 0.214785s to run, 
whereas this one

```
mymax = max(*mylist)
```

only 0.049693s !

The first one is more than four times slower.
So I was wondering : Is there an even better way to compute the max of a list in python?

Comment: `mymax = max(mylist)`.

Comment: That truely depends on the context. For example if you can keep the list sorted (descending) to begin with then this is simply `mylist[0]`. If you can relax the "list" requirement and use say a b-tree then again you can have O(1) complexity. The point is: algorithms don't mean much without context.

Comment: I think it will be hard to create a better implementation than `max`. However, I'd suggest that you check if the `numpy` implementation (i.e. `np.max`) is any faster.

Comment: With NumPy, your whole code becomes even faster: `import numpy; mylist = numpy.random.randint(0, 1000, 1000000); mymax = mylist2.max()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It is not. 0.086116s for numpy.max

Comment: Run `numpy.max` on a numpy array, not on a Python list, like I do in my code. Otherwise, NumPy will have to convert the list to an array first, which takes time.

Comment: @00 If you're not working with a numpy array in the first place, there's little point in bending over backwards to use numpy functions.

Comment: @deceze True, but this was a remark to the fact that the OP presumably used `numpy.max` on a list and got slower timings, which is then to "incorrect" use of `numpy.max`. Also, if the OP *is* using lists of 1 million or so elements, using NumPy is probably the way to go in the first place. If, on the other hand, the OP is generally using lists of a few dozen elements at most, this smells of premature optimisation, and the best advice to give then should be based on ergonomics instead of timings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Python interpreter, type `help(max)`, you will get:

```
Help on built-in function max in module __builtin__:

max(...)
    max(iterable[, key=func]) -> value
    max(a, b, c, ...[, key=func]) -> value

    With a single iterable argument, return its largest item.
    With two or more arguments, return the largest argument.
```

`max` is written in `C`, so it should already fast enough, your issue is using it in a not very right way.

Answer (score 5):

> even better way ...

I have no idea if it's more performant, but you technically don't need to unpack the list:

```
mymax = max(mylist)
```

Comment: It's indeed even better : 0.014653s for this one. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and best way to find max from the list is:

```
max(mylist)
```

You don't need to unpack the list.

Answer (score 0):

You should write simply:

```
mymax = max(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should just be these two lines.

```
mylist = [random.randint(0,1000) for _ in range(10**6)]
max_elm = max(mylist)
```

You do not have to trace through every element of the list.  List has many associated functions with it. Use them. It would take it about 0.015854835510253906 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But do you know why those associated functions are so much better than the one I write? Is it just because they are coded in C, or is there another reason for it?

Comment: @Rosome Python's inbuilt functions are coded in C, and these codes as we know run faster than any high level language, like Python. The linking required is much 'smoother' and 'quicker' for these library functions. Whenever you have a doubt, or want to know the list of available functions for anything, just type `dir("thing you want to look for")`. Like in this case, when you open Jupyter or any other editor, just type `dir(list)`, and you will see the list of functions that you have at your disposal. And remember, the connector here to link the module and the function inside is '.'.

Comment: @Rosome Here we are using `max`, which is an built-in function, and the list of these built-in functions can be found at: https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#map. These built in functions accept only parameters, hence we passed the list name as a parameter to `max` here.